# Multiple Source File Problem in C++

Tags: c++, header

I had a a problem in implementing a Multiple Source File

My function is like this:

```
inline bool TextContains(char *text, char ch) {
  while ( *text ) {
    if ( *text++ == ch )
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}

void Split(char *text, char *delims, vector<string> &words) {
  int beg;
  for (int i = 0; text[i]; ++i) {

    while ( text[i] && TextContains(delims, text[i]) )
      ++i;

    beg = i;

    while ( text[i] && !TextContains(delims, text[i]) )
      ++i;
      words.push_back( string(&text[beg], &text[i]) );
    }
}

string convertInt(int number)
{
   stringstream ss;
   ss << number;
   return ss.str();
}


string dateFormatChecker(const char *date){
string strdate=date;
char getdate[50];
strcpy_s(getdate, strdate.c_str());

vector<string> checkdate;
Split( getdate, "-", checkdate );
int year, month, day;
year=atoi(checkdate[0].c_str());
month=atoi(checkdate[1].c_str());
day=atoi(checkdate[2].c_str());

string checkyear, checkmonth, checkday, checkhour, checkminute, checksecond;

        checkyear = convertInt(year);
        if(month<10){
        checkmonth = "0" + convertInt(month);
        }
        else{
        checkmonth = convertInt(month);
        }
        if(day<10){
        checkday = "0" + convertInt(day);
        }
        else{
        checkday = convertInt(day);
        }

        if (checkyear.size() != checkdate[0].size()||
            checkmonth.size() != checkdate[1].size()||
            checkday.size() != checkdate[2].size()){
            return "";
        }
return date;
}

string dateandtimeFormatChecker(const char *dateandtime){
    string strdate=dateandtime;
    char getdateandtime[50];
    strcpy_s(getdateandtime, strdate.c_str());

    vector<string> checkdateandtime;
        Split( getdateandtime, "-: ", checkdateandtime );
    int year, month, day, hour, minute, second;
        year=atoi(checkdateandtime[0].c_str());
        month=atoi(checkdateandtime[1].c_str());
        day=atoi(checkdateandtime[2].c_str());
        hour=atoi(checkdateandtime[3].c_str());
        minute=atoi(checkdateandtime[4].c_str());
        second=atoi(checkdateandtime[5].c_str());

        string checkyear, checkmonth, checkday, checkhour, checkminute, checksecond;

        checkyear = convertInt(year);
        if(month<10){
        checkmonth = "0" + convertInt(month);
        }
        else{
        checkmonth = convertInt(month);
        }
        if(day<10){
        checkday = "0" + convertInt(day);
        }
        else{
        checkday = convertInt(day);
        }
        if(hour<10){
        checkhour = "0" + convertInt(hour);
        }
        else{
        checkhour = convertInt(hour);
        }
        if(minute<10){
        checkminute = "0" + convertInt(minute);
        }
        else{
        checkminute = convertInt(minute);
        }
        if(second<10){
        checksecond = "0" + convertInt(second);
        }
        else{
        checksecond = convertInt(second);
        }


        if (checkyear.size() != checkdateandtime[0].size()||
            checkmonth.size() != checkdateandtime[1].size()||
            checkday.size() != checkdateandtime[2].size()||
            checkhour.size() != checkdateandtime[3].size()||
            checkminute.size() != checkdateandtime[4].size()||
            checksecond.size() != checkdateandtime[5].size()){
            return "";
        }

    return dateandtime;     
}

string FormatPosDataXml (const char * SequenceNumber, const char * RetailStoreID, const char * WorkStationID, const char * BusinessDayDate, const char * BeginDateTime, const char * StartTransTime, const char * EndTransTime, const char * EndDateTime, const char * RawData){

string output;

string bdd, bdt, stt, ett, edt;

bdd = dateFormatChecker(BusinessDayDate);
bdt = dateandtimeFormatChecker(BeginDateTime);
stt = dateandtimeFormatChecker(StartTransTime);
ett = dateandtimeFormatChecker(EndTransTime);
edt = dateandtimeFormatChecker(EndDateTime);

cout << "<Transaction>\n\t<RetailStoreID>"
     << RetailStoreID   << "</RetailStoreID>\n\t<WorkStationID>"
     << WorkStationID   << "</WorkStationID>\n\t<SequenceNumber>"
     << SequenceNumber  << "</SequenceNumber>\n\t<BusinessDayDate>"
     << bdd             << "</BusinessDayDate>\n\t<BeginDateTime>"
     << bdt             << "</BeginDateTime>\n\t<StartTransTime>"
     << stt             << "</StartTransTime>\n\t<EndTransTime>"
     << ett             << "</EndTransTime>\n\t<EndDateTime>"
     << edt             << "</EndDateTime>\n\t<RawData>"
     << RawData         << "</RawData>\n</Transaction>";

output = _getch();
return output; 
}

string getInput(char *data){
vector<string> words;

Split( data, ",", words );

  char SN[11], RSI[200], WSI[200], BDD[100], BDT[100], STT[100], ETT[100], EDT[100], RD[100];

  strcpy_s(SN, words[0].c_str());
  strcpy_s(RSI, words[1].c_str());
  strcpy_s(WSI, words[2].c_str()); 
  strcpy_s(BDD, words[3].c_str());
  strcpy_s(BDT, words[4].c_str());
  strcpy_s(STT, words[5].c_str());
  strcpy_s(ETT, words[6].c_str());
  strcpy_s(EDT, words[7].c_str());
  strcpy_s(RD, words[8].c_str());

  string PosData;
  PosData = FormatPosDataXml(SN,RSI,WSI,BDD,BDT,STT,ETT,EDT,RD);

return PosData;

}
```

But whenever I put it in the header file like this :

```
string getInput(char *data);
```

I always get plenty of errors like undeclared identifier, int string redefinition and so on...

Anyone can you help me?

Comment: What plenty of errors? why don't you post them too?

Comment: term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments 

'checkday' : undeclared identifier


'int string' : redefinition 

syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'checkyear' 

left of '.c_str' must have class/struct/union

left of '.size' must have class/struct/union

'return' : cannot convert from 'const char *' to 'int' 

'convertInt' : inconsistent return statement

Comment: 'dateFormatChecker' : inconsistent return statement 

'strcpy_s' : function does not take 2 arguments 


'string' : ambiguous symbol

'std::vector' : 'string' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty' 

missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int 

cannot overload functions distinguished by return type alone  I remove the other Errors because its too many..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tnx for the information guys.. i finally got the right codes.

first i must put headers on the function so that it wont prompt some errors.

THen I will remove the usual header except the header that i made. and then I got it...

Answer (score 0):

I think the order of header #includes might be the source of the problem.

Comment: Then there's a greater evil at work - the order you put your #includes should generally not affect your program's ability to compile.

Comment: What about the order of the includes? These are my headers:#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>#include "Function.h"

Comment: cyclic dependency perhaps? class A references class B, which in itself references class A

Answer (score 0):

Regarding this error:

> 'string' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty'

and

> ambiguous symbol 'std::vector'

Are you being consistent with your usage of "std::" versus "using namespace std;"?

Comment: i am only using namespace std;